# Build change history from table with historical row values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table that is storing historical values for data in other table:

```
ObjectId | Value | UpdatedAt
1        |     A | 2020-07-15
1        |     B | 2020-07-16
1        |     C | 2020-07-17
2        |     A | 2020-07-15
2        |     B | 2020-07-16
```

Now I need to generate from such table "change log" which will show what was old value, new value and when update occur:

```
ObjectId | OldValue | NewValue | UpdatedAt
1        |     A    |        B | 2020-07-16
1        |     B    |        C | 2020-07-17
2        |     A    |        B | 2020-07-16
```

Unfortunately, I can't change structure of the existing table and can't put old value there, I need a query to extract this.

Comment: updated example with non-number values, I need varchars actually, so min/max isn't an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use window function `lead()` to do partition on `ObjectId`. Here is the [demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/dae45/4).

```
select
  ObjectId,
  Value,
  NewValue,
  UpdatedAt
from
(
  select
    ObjectId,
    Value,
    lead(value) over (partition by ObjectId order by UpdatedAt) as NewValue,
    lead(UpdatedAt) over (partition by ObjectId order by UpdatedAt) as UpdatedAt
  from Table1
) subq
where NewValue is not null
order by ObjectId
```

output:

```
| ObjectId  Value NewValue  UpdatedAt |
*-------------------------------------*
|  1        1       2      2020-07-16 |
|  1        2       3      2020-07-17 |
|  2        1       2      2020-07-16 |
```

Comment: This looks promising, I will give it a try and let you know

Comment: yes definietely, just want to confirm it's ok before that

Answer (score 1):

You can use windowing functions to achieve the result.

```sql
DECLARE @historyTable table(ObjectId int, Value int, UpdatedAt date)

insert into @historyTable values
(1        ,     1 ,'2020-07-15'),
(1        ,     2 ,'2020-07-16'),
(1        ,     3 ,'2020-07-17'),
(2        ,     1 ,'2020-07-15'),
(2        ,     2 ,'2020-07-16');

SELECT * from
(
SELECT objectid, value as oldvalue,
lead(value,1) over (partition by objectid order by updatedat) as newvalue,
lead(UpdatedAt,1) over (partition by objectid order by updatedat) as updatedat
FROM @historyTable
) as t
where t.updatedat is not null
```

```
+----------+----------+----------+------------+
| objectid | oldvalue | newvalue | updatedat  |
+----------+----------+----------+------------+
|        1 |        1 |        2 | 2020-07-16 |
|        1 |        2 |        3 | 2020-07-17 |
|        2 |        1 |        2 | 2020-07-16 |
+----------+----------+----------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
with cte as (
     select row_number() over (partition by objectid order by UpdatedAt ) rnk,[ObjectId], [Value], [UpdatedAt]
     from T
)
select t1.ObjectId,t2.Value as OldValue ,t1.Value as NewValue ,t1.UpdatedAt
from (
    select * from cte 
    where rnk <> 1
) t1
left join cte t2 on t1.objectid =t2.objectid and t1.rnk -1 = t2.rnk
```

table script :

```sql
CREATE TABLE T
    ([ObjectId] int, [Value] int, [UpdatedAt] datetime)
;
    
INSERT INTO T
    ([ObjectId], [Value], [UpdatedAt])
VALUES
    (1, 1, '2020-07-15 00:00:00'),
    (1, 2, '2020-07-16 00:00:00'),
    (1, 3, '2020-07-17 00:00:00'),
    (2, 1, '2020-07-15 00:00:00'),
    (2, 2, '2020-07-16 00:00:00')
;
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=171d3244cea43c2dea90ea886f9ab182)

[image]

Comment: This isn't the output which the OP is expecting.

Answer (score 0):

```
    with changeLogTemp as
    (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by ObjectId,UpdatedAt ) row_number ,* from changeLog
    )
    
    select 
    l.ObjectId,
    l.Value OldValue,
    r.Value NewValue,
    r.UpdatedAt 
    
    from changeLogTemp l 
    left join changeLogTemp r on l.ObjectId =r.ObjectId and l.row_number =r.row_number-1
    where r.UpdatedAt is not null
```

You can also use `Widowfunction (Lead())` to solve this situation

But the proposed solution is very simple
And at the same time, it is very useful for similar operations(`computational and comparative`) between rows and two or more columns